# How to handle errors with more than one unique field in Mongodb Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Let's say I have two fields that have to be unique, username and email. When I try to console.log(err) returned from the try catch, err.code is the only thing that allows you to distinguish if its a unique error or not, but how can I distinguish whether it was a username unique error or an email unique error.

Here is my function to check errors

```
const handleErrors = (err) => {
    let errors = { username: '', password: '', email: '', firstname: '', lastname: ''}
    if (err.code === 11000)
    {
        console.log(err);
        //check if username error or email error
    }
    if (err.message.includes('Users validation failed'))
    {
        Object.values(err.errors).forEach(({properties}) => {
            errors[properties.path] = properties.message;
        })
    }
    return errors;
}
```

here is my UsersModel.js

```
onst mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { isEmail } = require('validator');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [ true, "Username field can't be empty" ],
        minlength: [3, 'Username must be more than 3 characters'],
        maxlength: [20, 'Username must be less than 20 characters'],
        unique: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [ true, "Email field can't be empty" ],
        maxlength: [50, 'Email must be less than 50 characters'],
        unique: true,
        validate: [isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [ true, "Password field can't be empty" ],
        minlength: [8, 'Password must be more than 3 characters'],
    },
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: [ true, "First name field can't be empty" ],
        minlength: [3, 'First name must be more than 3 characters'],
        maxlength: [20, 'First name must be less than 20 characters'],
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: [ true, "Last name field can't be empty" ],
        minlength: [3, 'Last name must be more than 3 characters'],
        maxlength: [20, 'Last name must be less than 20 characters'],
    },
    points: {
        type: String,
        default: "0",
    },
})

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt);
    next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, all you have to do is use mongoose-unique-validator module, and then you can handle errors in the same way you handle other errors. Problem is you can't have a different error message as the default. So you have to handle it differently like this

```
const handleErrors = (err) => {
    let errors = { username: '', password: '', email: '', firstname: '', lastname: ''}
    if (err.message.includes('Users validation failed'))
    {
        Object.values(err.errors).forEach(({properties}) => {
            if (properties.message.includes('expected `email`'))
                errors[properties.path] = 'Email is already registered'
            else if (properties.message.includes('expected `username`'))
                errors[properties.path] = 'Username is already registered'
            else
                errors[properties.path] = properties.message;
        })
    }
    return errors;
}
```